# How to interpret telephone line for Arduino?

Tags: arduino, pwm

I wish to built my own "Dialler Capture" using Arduino.

Alarm panels use something called [Contact ID](http://www.voip-sip-sdk.com/p_582-ademco-contact-id-protocol-introduction-voip.html), that use the phone line to transfer "packets" (quotation marks are used because they aren't network data packets, they are [DTMF sequences](https://li0r.wordpress.com/contact-id-protocol/)).

I know that the phone line uses 48V while the Arduino uses 5V. I don't want to put 48V directly onto a controller!

I cam across the [M-8870 chip](https://people.ece.cornell.edu/land/courses/ece4760/FinalProjects/s2001/pr57/M-8870.PDF) which appears to convert DTMF to a byte (4-bits). Is this my only option?

Also, the Arduino doesn't understand DTMF. Even if I made a voltage drop to 5V, didn't use the DTMF converter (appears to be obsolete) it doesn't have an analogue input, only a PWM input.

May main question is, programming aside, how can I get an Arduino to understand DTMF using electronic components (that could be built on a breadboard)?

Comment: it does have an analogue input, in fact 6 of them (Uno anyway). You don't have 48v when the phone of 'off-hook'. Read how the 8870 works, you've got quite a lot to do in software.

Comment: "Contact ID" appears to be one of many Alarm protocols, in this case using common protocols to Cisco gateways like SPA3102 . You can generate 1400/2300 Hz from master clock and decode DTMF from M-8870 but look for SDK's that exist and many products/clones avail from China before reinventing the wheel.

Comment: "I wish to build my own 'Dialer Capture'" - Why?

Comment: I want to learn.

Answer (score 1):

In order to interface to the phone line you are looking for a SLIC (subscriber line interface circuit).  There are discrete designs and ICs like the ISL5585 that implement the interface.

Capturing DTMF on an arduino is going to be a challenge (code link below).  If you use an ARM instead (several ARM processors are supported by Arduino or you could use MBED/etc).  Here is an app note on the one algorithm you can use to detect the tones: https://www.silabs.com/documents/public/application-notes/an218.pdf

An implementation in C which could be used with Arduino or MBED can be found here:
http://phrack.org/issues/50/13.html

Here is one for the AVR:
https://github.com/PaulStoffregen/AVR_DTMF/blob/master/dtmf.c